# Is width, height, top, right, bottom and left crossbrowser when the position is absolute? IE, FF, Chrome, Safari and other browsers

Tags: html, css

Is width, height, top, right, bottom and left crossbrowser when the position is absolute? IE, FF, Chrome, Safari and other browsers

I want to position elements on screen and to be crossbrowser;
my options are: top, right, bottom and left
OR: top, height, left and width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Older versions of IE (I think the bug was fixed in time for IE7 but not IE6) don't support the setting of opposite edges.

So you can't absolutely position top **and** bottom or left **and** right in that browser.

Comment: but I can define top AND height AND left AND width?

Comment: Yes, you can. It is just opposite edges that have the problem.